# Cancelling out terms in sequence convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let's say that I had a sequence $(a_n : n \in \mathbb N)$ defined by $a_n := \frac {n-2}{n^2-5n+6}$. I want to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$ using a formal $\epsilon-N$ proof.

First, I let $0 \lt \epsilon$ and $L=0$. Then $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$ implies that $\frac{|n-2|}{|n-2||n-3|} \lt \epsilon$. My question is, where should I go from there? Should I cancel out the term $|n-2|$, because what if $n = 2$?. Then that would be impossible...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean $$a_n=\frac{n-2}{n^2-5n+6}$$

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: Trusting that you meant $n^2-5n+6$ in the denominator, note that in considering the limit as $n\to \infty$ you can ignore small $n$ entirely.  In particular, you can certainly assume that $n>2$.

Comment: @lulu I see now. I'll fix that little typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem.   $\quad$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need to show for this $\epsilon$? You need to prove there exists some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. It doesn't matter how large this index $n_0$ is, you just have to show it exists. So there is no problem with assuming it to be larger than $3$. So the next step is saying that for all $n\geq 4$ the statement $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n-3}<\epsilon$, and this happens when $\frac{1}{\epsilon}+3<n$. So we can take $n_0=\max\{[\frac{1}{\epsilon}+3]+1 ,\ 4\}$.

Comment: I kind of see already what you mean. But I still have a question about proving it once we have actually found a value for $n_0$. So suppose that $\frac{|n-2|}{|n-2||n-3|} \lt \epsilon$. Then $\frac{|n-2|}{|n-2||n-3|} =  \frac{1}{n-2}$. I'm confused on knowing how to write out the rest of the proof knowing the value for $n_0$. Would you do it with different cases? Can I please see how you would write it out yourself?

Comment: Well, in my answer I found the value of $n_0$. Now, if $n\geq n_0$ then from the definition of $n_0$ it follows that $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}+3$, which implies $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n-3}=\frac{n-2}{(n-2)(n-3)}=\frac{|n-2|}{|n-2||n-3|}=|a_n|=|a_n-0|$. So indeed if $n\geq n_0$ then $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm confused, because now you're saying that $\epsilon \gt |a_n - 0|$. But then wouldn't it contradict the fact that $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$ since $L = 0$?

Comment: But if $L=0$ then $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$ and $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ is exactly the same thing. So how do they contradict each other?

Comment: Never mind. I read that wrong and got it all mixed up. Anyway, I ended up getting something like $\frac{|n-2|}{|n-2||n-3|} = \frac{1}{n-3} \lt \frac{1}{N-3} \lt \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{\epsilon} + 3) - 3} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} = \epsilon$. Does this look right?

Comment: Yes, that's also a correct way to look at it.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, it would make a bit more sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, the only difference is that I started the inequality from $\epsilon$, you started from $|a_n-L|$. Other than that we got to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{n-2}{n^2-5n+6}<\frac{2}{n}$$ for $$n\geq n_0$$ Multiplying with $n,n^2-5n+6$ we get
$$n^2-2n<2n^2-10n+12$$ so 
$$0<n^2-8n+12$$, this is fulfilled for $$n\geq 6$$

Comment: But I'm still having trouble finding what $n_0$ is...